# Call method with callback in array of ES6 classes

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapreduce, ecmascript-6, reduce

I have an array of simple ES6 classes. Each class has a constructor and an hello method that accepts a callback. I need to iterate that array and call the hello method for each class. Each callback has to finish before I want to emit a generic event. I'm just not sure the best way to do this.

```
let todo = this.instance.map((obj, i) => {
    return obj.module.hello((cb) => {
        cb();
    });
}); 

Promise.all([
  todo
]).then(() => {
    console.log('done?');
    //emitter.emit('ready');
});
```

My classes look like this.

```
class Hero extends Abstract {

  constructor (options) {
    super(options);
  }

  hello(cb) {
      console.log('Hello || HeroClass');
      setTimeout(() => {
          cb();
      }, 2000);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is `instance` an array of `Hero` instances?

Comment: Just an example class.

Comment: You should rewrite those `hello` methods to return promises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of promises like this:

```
let todo = this.instance.map((obj, i) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       obj.module.hello(err => err ? reject(err) : resolve());
    });
}); 

Promise.all(todo).then(() => {
    console.log('done?');
    //emitter.emit('ready');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You must return promises from the mapping function, then you can await them with `Promise.all`:

```
let todo = this.instance.map((obj, i) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => 
        obj.module.hello(resolve)
    )
});

Promise.all(todo).then(() => {
    console.log('done?');
});
```

Comment: let todo = this.instance.map((obj, i) => {
         return new Promise((resolve) => {
             obj.module.hello(resolve);
         })
     });